# Market share dax measure - DAX

Tags: excel, dax

I have a simple dax measure that calculates market share % for the below table.

| Row Labels | Category | Eaches | Total cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Supplier1 | Accessories | 610 | £ 73,541.44 |
| Supplier1 | CRT-D | 17 | £ 193,078.93 |
| Supplier1 | DC ICD | 23 | £ 187,373.50 |
| Supplier1 | Leads | 86 | £ 45,835.64 |
| Supplier1 | SC ICD | 7 | £ 54,115.50 |
| Supplier2 | Accessories | 52 | £ 8,189.75 |
| Supplier2 | CRT-D | 7 | £ 66,065.71 |
| Supplier2 | DC ICD | 3 | £ 27,877.80 |
| Supplier2 | Leads | 34 | £ 33,277.53 |
| Supplier2 | S ICD | 20 | £ 223,201.00 |
| Supplier3 | Accessories | 1338 | £ 26,657.85 |
| Supplier3 | CRT-D | 18 | £ 261,798.58 |
| Supplier3 | DC ICD | 15 | £ 190,276.96 |
| Supplier3 | Leads | 292 | £ 93,502.09 |
| Supplier3 | SC ICD | 6 | £ 75,402.00 |

Dax measure:

```
=DIVIDE(
SUM(EACHES),CALCULATE(
SUM(EACHES),ALL(SUPPLIER)))
```

However, i was instructed to calculate market share for Category "DC ICD" and "SC ICD" together which really bugs me as i can't figure it out how to write this in DAX. As an example Excel formula for supplier 1 would look like this:

`=(23+7)/(23+7+3+15+6)`.

Could someone kindly advise how to move this into DAX please?

Comment: What visual you are  going to use?

Comment: No visuals. This a simple pivot in macro enabled spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope, it works for your solution

```
Correct_Measure = 
// It only gives sum of DC ICD AND SC ICD but considers suppliers
VAR ONLY_DCICD_SCICD_SUM = 
CALCULATE(
        SUM(Sheet1[Eaches]), 
        Sheet1[Category] IN {"DC ICD", "SC ICD"}
)
// It will give you sum of DC ICD AND SC ICD but consider for all suppliers (remove any filter for supplier all -> remove_filters)
VAR ALL_SUPPLIER_DCICD_SCICD = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(Sheet1[Eaches]),
    Sheet1[Category] IN {"SC ICD", "DC ICD"},
    ALL(Sheet1[Row Labels])
)
// It will return the ratio .
RETURN 
    DIVIDE(
        ONLY_DCICD_SCICD_SUM,
        ALL_SUPPLIER_DCICD_SCICD
    )    
// Thanks
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Something like this may work

```
=DIVIDE(
       CALCULATE(
                SUM(EACHES)
                ,OR(
                   'table'[CATEGORY]="DC ICD
                   ,'table'[CATEGORY]="SC ICD"   
                )
    )        
    ,CALCULATE(
              SUM(EACHES)
              ,ALL(SUPPLIER)
              ,OR(
                  'table'[CATEGORY]="DC ICD"
                  ,'table'[CATEGORY]="SC ICD"   
               )
      )
)
```

If you want to see results only in a certain row then

```
=
VAR Result =
      DIVIDE(
         CALCULATE(
                       SUM(EACHES)
                       ,'Table'[CATEGORY] in {'DC ICD','SC ICD'}   
                        )
             )        
              ,CALCULATE(
                        SUM(EACHES)
                        ,ALL(SUPPLIER)
                        ,'Table'[CATEGORY] in {'DC ICD','SC ICD'}   
              )
        )

RETURN
      IF(
         SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[CATEGORY]) in {'DC ICD','SC ICD'}   
         ,Result
         ,BLANK()
       )
```

Comment: Hi! Thank for this I really appreciate it however the problem is, this code - selectedvalue to be exact - will not work in a measure on pivot table.

Comment: does the first suggestion gives you a result?

Comment: I mean selectedvalue could be altered. But if the approach itself does not works, then better to think about other solution.

Comment: Yes, that is spot on thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
VAR x1 =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( [Eaches] ),
    KEEPFILTERS ( 'YourTable'[Category] IN { "DC ICD", "SC ICD" } )
)
VAR x2 =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( [Eaches] ),
    KEEPFILTERS ( 'YourTable'[Category] IN { "DC ICD", "SC ICD" } ),
    ALL ( 'YourTable'[Suppliers] )
)
RETURN
DIVIDE ( x1, x2 )
```